# Handling 404 error Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

I try to redirect all my 404 error on my web site following those docs :

> http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page

So I edited my error.php :

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com');
exit;
}

        if { (!isset($this->error)) {
                $this->error = JError::raiseWarning(404, JText::_('JERROR_ALERTNOAUTHOR'));
                $this->debug = false;
        }

//get language and direction
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->language = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;
?>
```

But when I clic on a link that should redirect me to a 404 error page - which should now redirect to my home page, it goes to the following link instead :

> http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?Itemid=359

How may I solve that problem ?

Comment: Redirecting 404s to your homepage is a bad idea. If the page is gone you need to serve a 404 otherwise Google is going to give you problems. You should use a custom 404 error page with a search function and/or other relevant links. See below for the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla needs an itemID when building a page. My guess is that your default page is item ID 359. Joomla is appending that to the URL most likely because you do not have SEF URLs with rewrite turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Correct code that you need (and more general) is:

```html
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
header('Location: /index.php');
exit;
}
```

Some suggested the below, but I just want to redirect to main page not to an article:

```html
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=999');
exit;
}
```